# Dynamically position labels on ListPlot

Tags: manipulate, labeling, plotting

When it comes to labelling every single point on a `ListPlot` there might be some labels overlapping. Thus, I would like to manually position the labels with a `Line` linking them to their associated point.

The following shows the idea:

```
coord={{0,0},{1,1}};
Manipulate[
  Show[
   Graphics[{Red,Line[{#2,1.02*#}]&@@@Thread[{pt,coord}]}],
   ListPlot[{coord}],ImageSize->250],    
{{pt,coord},Locator,Appearance->(#&/@{"a","b"})}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When it comes to more than one dataset I'm having an issue.

```
coord = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}};
coord1 = {{-1, 1}, {2, 0}};
Manipulate[
  Show[
    Graphics[{Red, Line[{#2, 1.02*#}] & @@@ Thread[{pt, coord}], 
              Blue, Line[{#2, 1.02*#}] & @@@ Thread[{pt1, coord1}]}], 
    ListPlot[{coord, coord1}]],
  {{pt, coord}, Locator, Appearance -> (# & /@ {"a", "b"})},
  {{pt1, coord1}, Locator, Appearance -> (# & /@ {"c", "d"})}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Introduction To Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html)

> Due to internal limitations, it is not possible to combine individual Locator variables with a variable that is a list of multiple Locator variables: you can have only one multipoint Locator variable in a Manipulate. ...

A work-around:

```
coord = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}};
coord1 = {{-1, 1}, {2, 0}};
coords = Join[coord, coord1];

Manipulate[Show[Graphics[{Red, Line[{#2, 1.02*#}] & @@@ Thread[{pts[[;; 2]], coord}], 
                          Blue,Line[{#2, 1.02*#}] & @@@ Thread[{pts[[3 ;;]], coord1}]}], 
                ListPlot[{coord, coord1}]], 
          {{pts, coords}, Locator, Appearance -> (# & /@ {"a", "b", "c", "d"})}]
```

Comment: Ah, I guess there is no other way when using `Manipulate` then, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The construct (# & /@ {"a", "b", "c", "d"}) can be simplified to just {"a", "b", "c", "d"}

Comment: @BobHanlon In that simple case indeed :)

Comment: @Öskå, If you do not need all this inside `Manipulate` for other reasons, you might consider using `Locator` as a graphics primitive as in `ListPlot[Sort@RandomInteger[10, {20, 2}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All] /. Point[x_] :> Locator /@ x`..

Comment: @kguler I don't need the `Manipulate` indeed. I'm currently facing the fact that `Locator`s disappear when being exported, with that method they are exported. So that might be the key :) One problem remains, I have right now no clue how to adapt your comment to the example in the question.. :)